# Can we convert PDF files to HTML using C,C++,or Java (any language)?

Tags: java, c++, html, pdf

I need to convert PDF files into HTML files (IOS platform) so that I can annotate the HTML page using Javascript. I had some success in annotating HTML pages, so if I can convert PDF to HTML I can complete my task. How can I do the conversion?

Comment: Please, reformulate the question and be more specific. What platform are you developing on? Which language are you using? Did you look for similar questions before asking?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=pdf+to+html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Converting FROM PDF is generally Very Hard (at best).

PDF contains drawing instructions.  "Line from here to there", "these characters at these coordinates".  There's *usually* no information about the logical meaning of these lines, characters, and images, though "Document Structure" is becoming more common.

Without "document structure" and "marked content" it is Very Hard to go from "a pile of lines and characters" to "a table with this *information* in these columns and rows".

Not impossible, just Very Hard.

And people who have worked on this problem aren't all that interested in sharing their code for free.

Comment: http://bisqwit.iki.fi/source/pdf2simplehtml.html -> Here some source code to convert pdf to html. Only simple text will be converted to html.

Comment: And that code comes with a pile of disclaimers (and coupd use a few more I'd imagine).  I stand by my assessment.

Comment: Hi Mark, Using Apple native API support, i am now able to efficiently highlight the PDF search string. Can you please give me some idea,How to get selected (Annotated) text's in PDF ? I know its  very difficult get the each character location in PDF page so that i can map. Thanks!! Naveen

Comment: Does the Apple API tell you where its putting its highlights?  Does it tell you how its adding these highlights?  Can you show us a PDF containing said highlights so we can answer the second question ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

It will be hard to convert any pdf, some of them are too complicated for HTML.

Take a look at [libpoppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/) it has already pdf2html functions and it is open source, you can always extends it, so it fits yours requirements.

Comment: Can u pls give me the link to libpoppler.

Comment: Can i integrate libpoppler code in my IOS program ? I downloaded that code in my iMac. But i am clueless how to use it in my project :(

Comment: Try to compile it and look after 'pdftohtml.cc'. I don't know, if you can integrate poppler in your programm, it is under GPL.